# How to secure post request between two CakePHP application

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

I have created two CakePHP applications on two different servers.

The **application A** need to send an array of data to **application B**  in POST using curl :

```
$ch = curl_init();  
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,"http://example.com/application_B");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  
$output=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

What is the best practice to make sure application **application B** won't accept any other request that request coming from **application A** ?
Is checking IP address enough ? Or CakePHP has built in method to do so ?

PS: I known [HttpSocket](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/fr/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html) is better than CURL in CakePHP but my **application A** use CakePHP 1.1 (not my will)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this. Cake doesn't provide any, only auth adapters to check for certain auth systems.

First use a **HTTPS** connection between the apps. Disable HTTP for the API.

You can use a stateless auth using user/pass and a token. Request a token by sending user/pass and get a time limited token back that is bound to the IP that requested it as well. Your auth adapters will deal with the requests.

Or simply go straight for [Oauth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth).

Comment: Thanks! I will give a try with Oauth. Too bad CakePHP does not provide ways to secure that by default.

Answer (score 1):

As burzum said there are many ways. A **very very** simple way would be to have the key string value on both applications. Hash the post data with this key on **Application A** and pass the hash value along with your data array. Then hash the data (without the hash value) again on **Application B**. Compare the two hash. If the hash values are the same then the data are correct.